# @UseGuards for @ResolveField in NestJS GraphQL

Tags: graphql, nestjs

I want to use @UseGuards functionality for a @ResolveField, because I want the main query to be public, but specific things to be visible only for specific users.
I don't want to use another query or another type of guard.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Just found out about field resolver enhancers :)

```
GraphQLModule.forRoot({
  fieldResolverEnhancers: ['guards'],
  ...
}
```

=> guards can be used for @ResolveFields too :)

Keep in mind that this is not set by default in NestJS because using Guards for @ResolveFields can be dangerous. For example, if you have 5 fields for the same resolver and you protect all of them with a Guard, the Guard will be called 5 times :)